# Get Vuetify icons to work when loading page from filesystem

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a vue project created with vue cli 3 and i am using Vuetify v2.0.19.

My project requires me to be able to build the project and output a single html file so that it can be downloaded and ran offline in a phonegap app(safari v13). I am able to meet all the requirements and get my project to show up in the phonegap app but the icons do not render. For example, where I use `<v-icon>info</v-icon>` it will render INFO, etc.

I have followed the Vuetify Quick-Start, Icons and Browser Support pages and several other Stack Overflow threads answers but can not get my icons to render.

**I basically need the fonts included in my single file.** When I load the page in the phonegap app or when serving from filesystem I get 'not found' errors in the console `(file:///D:/fonts/materialdesignicons-webfont.27cb2cf1.woff2)` I am aware the path is wrong but how can I get the icons to be part of the build?

Is this possible?

To get the single html file with js and css I added the npm packages `html-webpack-plugin` and `html-webpack-inline-source-plugin` and in my `vue.config.js` I have the following:

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const HtmlWebpackInlineSourcePlugin = require('html-webpack-inline-source-plugin');
module.exports = {
    css: {
        extract: false,
    },
    configureWebpack: {
      optimization: {
        splitChunks: false
      },
      plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
          filename: 'output/output.html',
          template: 'src/output-template.html',
          inlineSource: '.(js|css)$' // embed all javascript and css inline
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackInlineSourcePlugin()
      ]
    },
    transpileDependencies:[/node_modules[/\\\\]vuetify[/\\\\]/]
  }
```

and in `src/plugins/vuetify.js`

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib'
import '@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css'

Vue.use(Vuetify)

export default new Vuetify({
  icons: {
    iconfont: 'mdi',
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figure out how to get this working how I needed it using the [method described here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/icons#install-material-design-icons-js-svg).

```
 // plugins/vuetify.js

import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib'

Vue.use(Vuetify)

export default new Vuetify({
  icons: {
    iconfont: 'mdiSvg'
  }
})
```

And in the components that I am using the icons (using the mdi information icon for example)

```
<template>    
    ...
       <v-icon>{{svgPath}}</v-icon>
    ...
</template>
<script>
import {mdiInformation} from '@mdi/js'
  export default {
      ...
      data() {
          return {
              svgPath: mdiInformation
          }
      }
  }
</script>
```